# SQL Server - Group By, Join issue

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have an orders table, which has the following fields:

unid is the primary key field
order_reference is a system generated incrementing number
named_worker column will be set to 'Yes' if the order is a named worker order

I have one order, reference 'BCC-015212' and it's a named worker order.

The following query is using information from the orders table and gives me the expected results:

```
SELECT 'Order Number'=Case WHEN GROUPING(o.order_reference) = 1 Then 'Grand Total:' ELSE o.order_reference END,
'Orders Raised' = COUNT(distinct o.unid), 
'Named Workers' = SUM(CASE o.named_worker WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM orders o
WHERE o.order_reference = 'BCC-015212'
Group By o.order_reference
WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY o.order_reference

Returned Results:
Order Number | Orders Raised | Named Workers
Grand Total: | 1             | 1
BCC-015212   | 1             | 1
```

I'd like to be able to group this information by the agency name which is a column a different table called orderApplicants.

Order 'BCC-015212' has a total of 3 orderApplicants. 1 orderApplicant for Agency1 and 2 for Agency2.

OrderApplicant has a foreign key called order_unid linking to the order table via the unid field.

If I do a join to the OrderApplicants table, the query then gives me inaccurate results on the named worker column:

```
SELECT 'Order Number'=Case WHEN GROUPING(o.order_reference) = 1 Then 'Grand Total:' ELSE o.order_reference END,
'Agency'=Case WHEN GROUPING(oa.agency_name) = 1 Then 'Sub Total:' ELSE oa.agency_name END,
'Orders Raised' = COUNT(distinct o.unid),
'Named Workers' = SUM(CASE o.named_worker WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM orders o
Inner Join orderapplicants oa on oa.order_unid = o.unid
WHERE o.order_reference = 'BCC-015212'
Group By o.order_reference,oa.agency_name
WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY o.order_reference, oa.agency_name

Returned Results:
Order Number | Agency    | Orders Raised | Named Workers
Grand Total: | Sub Total:| 1             | 3
BCC-015212   | Sub Total:| 1             | 3
BCC-015212   | Agency1   | 1             | 1
BCC-015212   | Agency2   | 1             | 2

Required Results:
Order Number | Agency    | Orders Raised | Named Workers
Grand Total: | Sub Total:| 1             | 1
BCC-015212   | Sub Total:| 1             | 1
BCC-015212   | Agency1   | 1             | 1
BCC-015212   | Agency2   | 1             | 1
```

Is there a way for me to group by agency name but give me accurate information from information in the orders table such as named workers?

I've loaded a working example on rextester.com can be found here: http://rextester.com/SRX8309

Comment: TL:DR  Cant you make your question simpler? [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have already simplified it from the actual query I'm using in production (there's another 10 columns in the actual query). I guess I could simplify it further by taking out the orderapplicants select column the left join section. I just wanted to show that my initial query is already looking to information in the orderapplicants table before I tried to do the group by on the agency_name which then presents me with my issue.

Comment: Good luck, But I wont spend 30 min trying to understand your scenario. Try creating a working sample here http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler. Focus only on three things first. DbSchema, Sample Data, Current/Desire Output so we can know what it is about. Then you can provide aditional context/details

Comment: Also maybe forget about your whole problem, focus in a small section so once you solve it you can put it on the main query.

Comment: By testing your query, make sure that you get the correct results and then you will know that it works.

Comment: Here is how to give your specification. For each base table give a sentence template that makes a true statement from the columns of a row in it. Eg "order UNID was either submitted on date SUBMITTED_ON or was not submitted and SUBMITTED_ON  IS NULL, and ORDER_REFERENCE is ..." & "in order ORDER_UNID order applicant named NAME from agency ...". Then do the same for your query result using the base table templates plus conditions. ...

Comment: ... Eg "for some O.UID, ..., OA.ORDER_UNID, ... it is the case that O.ORDER_REFERENCE = OrderReference,... AND order UNID was either submitted ... AND in order ORDER_UNID order applicant... AND order O.ORDER_REFERENCE involved agency AGENCY_NAME ... offering a total of NamedWorkers and the total number of applicants from that agency for that order was OrderApplicants".

Comment: @juan-carlos-oropeza, I've taken your comments on board and simplified my question. I hope this helps to be clearer on what my issue is and whether there is a solution to it.

Comment: @philipxy, please see my edited question which I hope makes my post clearer.

Comment: Hi @philipxy,I meant the agency_name field on the orderApplicants table. The two tables are joined on orders.unid = orderApplicants.order_unid. I've added the expected results from the query I'd like.

Comment: Your question *does not explain what results you want*. There is a reason why I said to phrase things a certain way.

Comment: @philipxy I'd already added a required results section to the last code block. Also, there is a working example of my issue on the rextester.com site. [http://rextester.com/SRX8309](http://rextester.com/SRX8309)

Comment: Nothing you've written (question, comments or code) explains what "accurate information from information in the orders table" or "workers column is now not accurate" *mean*. (Ask yourself why you think something does.) Apparently what you want is not simple/obvious enough to be guessed/inferred from your example. (Anyway that's hope not communication.) Eg you don't explain why (BCC-015212, Agency2,1,1) is in the desired result. You don't give the condtions under which a row (OrderNumber, Agency, OrdersRaised, NamedWorkers) is in the desired result. I have told you what will make things clear.